# Using ARG command in a sub Dockerfile

Tags: jenkins, docker, dockerfile

I am creating my own `Dockerfile` based on the [Jenkins Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/jenkins) only to add some pre-installed packages in the image (build-essential, etc...).

In the Jenkins `Dockerfile` they used the [ARG command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/arg) to create the `jenkins` user and group: See [these lines](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/195787dca586b41971e2037b48d3f6dca04c9667/Dockerfile#L8-L11).

Here is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM  jenkins
USER  root
RUN   apt-get update && apt-get install -y build-essential
USER  jenkins
```

But when I build it to fit my `jenkins` host user by using this line:

```
docker build --tag my-jenkins \
    --build-arg user=jenkins \
    --build-arg group=jenkins \
    --build-arg uid=$(id -u jenkins) \
    --build-arg gid=$(id -g jenkins) \
    .
```

I have got this error:

```
One or more build-args [gid group uid user] were not consumed, failing build.
```

Is there a way to do this or is it impossible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's impossible. The image is already built (using the defaults). You could write a quick script to build your own jenkins image (passing the args) then build your sub-image from that.

Comment: So when and how would the `ARG` commands in the Jenkins Dockerfile be used? Is there any way for me as a consumer of the image to make use of them?